# MEAN Stack - pass variables from html view to ng-controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ng-controller

I have developed a profile page which contains several modules such as, let's say : personal info and friends.

Each modules is a ng-controller which makes database calls but I would like to be able to pass the id of the user of whom the profile is being displayed so that database calls are dynamics and retrieve data related to this user.

How I am supposed to do that?

Thanks in advance,

Manuel

*** Clarification ***
I am using express.js which handles authentication and session management (with Passport).
Once the user is logged in he reaches the "/profile" page.

I didn't particularly want to handle routing on several sides so I decided to handle all routing on Node side. So I have created routes for get and post calls.

Now, when the user arrives on "/profile" I would like the different modules (personnal info, friends, etc.) to update based on the person connected.

I managed to do non-dynamic call :

```
app.controller('UserInfo', [
'$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/users/info/1")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.user = response.data.local;      
    });
}
]);
```

But this doesn't depend on the context. So I would like now to create get calls the same way but being able to pass the id (or any other proper way) of the user to retreive his data.

Would you have any recommendation as to how to proceed? Any link to tutorials on how to handle this in multi-page MEAN application? Most of documents I found on the internet are related to single-page applications and don't answer my need.
Thanks!

Comment: use sessions in the server side.

Comment: You can use ngStorage to store the user related data into local storage which must be called once.
NOTE: Don't store password in your local storage.
For ex: If user gets logged in successfully, save it in localstorage and remove it when user log out.

Comment: How does your controller call database? Are you using Rest call with $resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your UI handle who am I, you will get some security breach.
Your server need to know who is connected. (with a cookie or something like that).

Here is an exemple : https://blog.nodejitsu.com/sessions-and-cookies-in-node/

Comment: Actually I am not even sure as to how I am building the application.

Comment: I am sorry for my previous comment, I accidentally hit enter... I will add some precision to my question

Comment: Same answer, you don't to pass anything to angular since your server can handle this, with HTTP Header

Comment: Thank you Steeve but I can't see any Angular in your link. You're suggesting that I retrieve the id of the user from the cookie stored in the HTTP header? Correct? Should I use Angular LocalStorage to do so, as mentionned by Manish?